# How can I save the entered values in an editText until the app is completely closed and destroyed?

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, kotlin, android-fragments

The values for editText that I have entered in one fragment disappear when I navigate to other fragments in the menu and then return to the first fragment.
Please tell how to avoid this, in terms of Kotlin code, in detail.

This is my Kotlin code of the fragment.

```
class EstimatorFragment : Fragment(){

    lateinit var etPerson:EditText
    lateinit var etPetrol:EditText
    lateinit var etElectricity:EditText
    lateinit var etWater:EditText
    lateinit var etLpg:EditText
    lateinit var etHouseTravel:EditText
    lateinit var etSchool:EditText
    lateinit var etVacation:EditText
    lateinit var btnGetResults:Button

     override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
     ): View? {

         val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_estimator, container, false)

         etPerson = view.findViewById(R.id.etPerson)
         etPetrol = view.findViewById(R.id.etPetrol)
         etElectricity = view.findViewById(R.id.etElectricity)
         etWater = view.findViewById(R.id.etWater)
         etLpg = view.findViewById(R.id.etLpg)
         etHouseTravel = view.findViewById(R.id.etHouseTravel)
         etSchool = view.findViewById(R.id.etSchool)
         etVacation = view.findViewById(R.id.etVacation)
         btnGetResults = view.findViewById(R.id.btnGetResults)

         btnGetResults.setOnClickListener {

            val registerUser = JSONObject()
            registerUser.put("name", etPerson.text)

            try {

                var person = etPerson.text.toString().toDouble()
                val mul1 = (person * 364).toFloat()
                val a = mul1.toString()

                var petrol = etPetrol.text.toString().toDouble()
                val mul2 = (petrol * (0.022772278*12)).toFloat()
                val b = mul2.toString()

                var electricity = etElectricity.text.toString().toDouble()
                val mul3 = (electricity * 12*(0.92/7)).toFloat()
                val c = mul3.toString()

                var water = etWater.text.toString().toDouble()
                val mul4 = (water * 179.4/325).toFloat()
                val d = mul4.toString()

                var lpg = etLpg.text.toString().toDouble()
                val mul5 = (lpg * 280.705152/0.6).toFloat()
                val e = mul5.toString()

                var travel = etHouseTravel.text.toString().toDouble()
                val mul6 = (travel * 83.72/1.5).toFloat()
                val f = mul6.toString()

                var school = etSchool.text.toString().toDouble()
                val mul7 = (school * 502.32/9).toFloat()
                val g = mul7.toString()

                var vacation = etVacation.text.toString().toDouble()
                val mul8 = (vacation * 383.333333/2000).toFloat()
                val h = mul8.toString()

                val fin = mul1 + mul2 + mul3 + mul4 + mul5 + mul6 + mul7 + mul8
                val final = fin.toString()

                val intent = Intent(activity, Results::class.java)
                intent.putExtra("A", a)
                intent.putExtra("B", b)
                intent.putExtra("C", c)
                intent.putExtra("D", d)
                intent.putExtra("E", e)
                intent.putExtra("F", f)
                intent.putExtra("G", g)
                intent.putExtra("H", h)
                intent.putExtra("FIN", final)

                startActivity(intent)

            } catch(e:NumberFormatException ) {
                val alterDialog = AlertDialog.Builder(activity as Context)
                alterDialog.setTitle("Enter All The Values!")
                alterDialog.setMessage("Enter 0 if any block is blank!")
                alterDialog.setPositiveButton("Ok") { _, _ ->
                }

                alterDialog.create()
                alterDialog.show()
            }
        }

         return view
    }
```

This the main activity class code which connects the menu items, navigations etc

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var drawerLayout: DrawerLayout
    lateinit var coordinatorLayout: CoordinatorLayout
    lateinit var toolbar: Toolbar
    lateinit var frameLayout: FrameLayout
    lateinit var navigationView: NavigationView

    var previousMenuItem: MenuItem? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout)
        coordinatorLayout = findViewById(R.id.coordinatorLayout)
        toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar)
        frameLayout = findViewById(R.id.frame)
        navigationView = findViewById(R.id.navigationView)

        setUpToolbar()
        openEstimator()

        val actionBarDrawerToggle = ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this@MainActivity,
            drawerLayout,
            R.string.open_drawer,
            R.string.close_drawer
        )
        drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle)
        actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState()

        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener {

            if (previousMenuItem != null){
                previousMenuItem?.isChecked = false
            }

            it.isCheckable = true
            it.isChecked = true
            previousMenuItem = it

            when(it.itemId){
                R.id.estimator -> {
                    openEstimator()
                    drawerLayout.closeDrawers()
                }

                R.id.aboutApp -> {
                    supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                        .replace(
                            R.id.frame,
                            AboutAppFragment()
                        )
                        .commit()

                    supportActionBar?.title = "About App"
                    drawerLayout.closeDrawers()
                }
            }
            return@setNavigationItemSelectedListener true
        }
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {

        val id = item.itemId

        if (id == android.R.id.home){
            drawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }

    fun openEstimator(){
        val fragment = EstimatorFragment()
        val transaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        transaction.replace(R.id.frame, fragment)
        transaction.commit()
        supportActionBar?.title = "Estimator"
        navigationView.setCheckedItem(R.id.estimator)
    }

    fun setUpToolbar() {
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
        supportActionBar?.title = "Toolbar Title"
        supportActionBar?.setHomeButtonEnabled(true)
        supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)

    }

    override fun onBackPressed() {
        val frag = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.frame)

        when(frag){
            !is EstimatorFragment -> openEstimator()

            else -> super.onBackPressed()
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I recommend you to use NAVIGATION COMPONENTS, you get a clearer code in terms of navigation.
Now, if you wanna save this values for more than 2 or 3 fragments, I recommend you to create a SharedViewModel, and there you can save the data, so you can get it in all fragment that it is instantiated.

- Create a DATA CLASS with with 8 elements with default empty values:

//This is the object model

```
data class EditTextData(
   var person: String = "",
   var petrol: String = "",
 ...
)
```

- Now create the SharedViewModel and create the object where we store the values, I reccomend you to use Flow but you can use LiveData too

//The values are gonna store here

```
private var _valuesOfEditText = EditTextData()
```

//Call this to storage the values

```
fun saveData(data: EditTextData){
       _values = data
}
```

//Call this to obtain the values

```
fun getData(): Flow<EditTextData>{
   return flow {
      emit(_value)
   }
}
```

- In EstimatorFragment create a function that save the data in the viewModel(it can't be private) and one to read the data(this could be private)

//You can always call obtainData() function or you can improve it by preventing it from being called only when necessary, I'll leave it to you ;)

```
fun saveDataInViewModel(){
   sharedViewModel.saveData(
      EditTextData(
         etPerson.text.toString(),
         etPetrol.text.toString(),
         ...
        )
    )
}


private fun obtainData(){
   lifecycleScope.launch {
      sharedViewModel.getData().collectLatest{data->
         if(data.person.isNotEmpty){
            etPerson.setText(data.person)
            etPetrol.setText(data.petrol)
            ...
         }
      }
   }
}
```

- Finally.

In your MainActivity when you call openEstimator(), add this line at the end

```
 fragment.saveDataInViewModel()
```

Sorry if there is a mistake in the last step, but I don't manage my navigation like this, even so I'm sure that you cand find the way in case there is an error in the latter. In case you can't find a way, let me know. Have a good day.

Just one more thing
If you have : A->B->C->D (fragments)
and you instantiate this sharedViewModel in A, B and D, I think when you arrive D, the data will no longer exist, because when you are in C the SharedViewModel will gona die, so I think for prevent it, is recommended that as long as you want to keep this data, there is no fragment through which you would not instantiate this SharedViewModel

**IMPORTANT: BE SURE THAT YOUR SHARED VIEWMODEL IS WELL CREATED**

Comment: I put the functions fun saveData() and fun getData() in the data class EditTextTataClass(....){}  inside the flower brackets . But in getData(), the _value is not globally defined. So it is giving me error. So please tell how to do the functions saveData() and getData() clearly.   And also the functions saveDataInViewModel() and obtainData() should be put in the flower brackets of data class right?  Im just a Android Studio beginner, sorry if my doubt was silly.

Comment: And i also dont know how to do sharedViewModel  :(

Comment: @RushiMayur No, the saveData() and getData() should be inside of the ViewModel. The dataClass object must be in other file and alone. Create the shared viewModel with this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=THt9QISnIMQ&ab_channel=Stevdza-San . And the saveDatainViewModel should be in the Estimator fragment, out of onCreateView but inside of the EstimatorFragment class. So then inside of the onViewCreated(you have to override this method) you call the function obtainData()